# How to Resize Background Images to fit iPad Screens

Tags: css, iphone, ipad, background-image, image-resizing

I'm running into a problem. When I view my website on a computer and phone, it's built perfectly; but, when I pull it up on an iPad, the background images are like blown up. My website is http://www.zwdalpha.com/, any help will be very appreciated! Also, my Github is https://github.com/zcsmouse970/zwdalpha

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us the issue (rather than linking your entire site which is prone to link decay).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue appears to be to do with background-attachment: fixed not behaving as expected.

Try `background-attachment: scroll`

Comment: Just checked on Caniuse and it appears that iOS still doesn't support `background-attachment: fixed` [http://caniuse.com/#feat=background-attachment](http://caniuse.com/#feat=background-attachment)

Answer (score 1):

To address the issue, you first need to understand what is happening. Background image sizes are handled with the `background-size` attribute, which you currently have set to `cover`. `cover` is great for large screens because it makes sure the image "covers" the height of the element. This allows for clipping on the sides to make sure it fills from top to bottom. `contain` is the opposite of that. It makes sure you can see the entire image at all times. It does this by making sure the width is 100% and the height is left to clip or expand. When you see on tablets and smaller that the images are "blown up", the CSS is making sure that the entire content area is filled with the image, and it does this by making sure the height of the image fills the content pane. Here's where we get a little more detailed.

You have your images setup as `fixed`. Obviously this was the effect you were going for, but lets think about what needs to happen here. Now the image needs to be covering the screen from top to bottom because it is able to be viewed anywhere the content pane is while being `fixed`. So now your image is covering the entire viewport. You can see the changes it makes when you change it to `background-attachment:scroll;`. It instead fits the image into the content pane instead of the viewport.

All of that being said, the way you can change this is by implementing media queries and switching backgrounds to cropped versions that are more appropriate to the viewing dimensions.